# google keyboard crashes after I'm adding words to userdictionary in my program

Tags: android, sqlite, android-userdictionary

Seems like it should work. And I can see words in User Dictionaries in Settings after importing them.

```
public static void addWord(Context context, String word, Locale locale) {

        final int COLUMN_COUNT = 5;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(COLUMN_COUNT);
        values.put(UserDictionary.Words.WORD, word);
        values.put(UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY, DEFAULT_FREQUENCY);
        values.put(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE, null == locale ? null : locale.toString());
        values.put(UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID, 0); // TODO: Get App UID
        values.put(UserDictionary.Words.SHORTCUT, "");
        resovler.insert(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, values);

       }
    }
```

But instead google keyboard is crushes with this error (I can see it in logcat)

```
Process: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin, PID: 30183
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.makedict.FusionDictionary.add(FusionDictionary.java:486)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.makedict.FusionDictionary.add(FusionDictionary.java:401)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.DictionaryWriter.addUnigramWord(DictionaryWriter.java:72)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary.addWord(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:273)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.UserBinaryDictionary.addWords(UserBinaryDictionary.java:253)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.UserBinaryDictionary.loadDictionaryAsync(UserBinaryDictionary.java:181)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary.writeBinaryDictionary(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:542)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary.access$700(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:48)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary$12.run(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:630)
        at com.android.inputmethod.latin.utils.PrioritizedSerialExecutor$1.run(PrioritizedSerialExecutor.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

After this crash everything seems to work. Spellchecker can see imported words.

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparantly was with adding empty string to the dictionary somehow.